# How to access another controller's property from another controller (not from a template)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My Application has two controllers, LoginController and RsvpController. I want to load a list of Rsvps  which are relevant to the current login.

My login code seems to work -- but I'm having trouble avoiding the following warning:
 "DEPRECATION: Controller#controllerFor is deprecated, please use Controller#needs instead"

I also suspect I'm not doing things the ember way, so I'd appreciate any comments as to how to improve this code to use more ember functionality.

Here is the controller:

```
App.RsvpController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['login'],   // borrows from login controller
    content: [],

    loadModel : function() {
        var theCode = this.controllerFor('login').get('code');
        console.log("Loading Model for code " + theCode);

        var rsvpArray = App.Rsvp.find({
            code : theCode
        });
        this.set('content', rsvpArray);

        rsvpArray.addObserver('isLoaded', function() {
            console.log("Loaded rsvpArray" + Em.inspect(this));
        });


    }.property('controllers.login.code'),       // reload model if the user changes login
});
```

Here is part of index.html:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="rsvp">
    <p>placeholder for <b>RSVP</b></p>

    {{#if controllers.login.name }}
        <!-- rsvp code here -->
        Logged in with code {{controllers.login.code}}

        {{ loadModel }} <!-- call loadModel function to populate model when this is rendered -->

        {{#each model}}
            <p>givenName {{givenname}}</p>
        {{/each}}

    {{else}}
        <i>Please login first!</i>
    {{/if}}

</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You where almost there, in your template you are doing things right, the deprecation warning comes from the call to `controllerFor` which you can avoid getting your login controller like so `this.get('controllers.login')`, here your code modified:

```
App.RsvpController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['login'], // borrows from login controller
  content: [],

  loadModel : function() {
    var theCode = this.get('controllers.login.code'); // here the change
    console.log("Loading Model for code " + theCode);

    var rsvpArray = App.Rsvp.find({
      code : theCode
    });
    this.set('content', rsvpArray);

    rsvpArray.addObserver('isLoaded', function() {
      console.log("Loaded rsvpArray" + Em.inspect(this));
    });

  }.property('controllers.login.code'), // reload model if the user changes login
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. I'm sure I tried that (but perhaps something else was broken when I tried that syntax)